# How to get the latest Page Value for the iTestContext attributes in Playwright Java (By Overriding)

Tags: java, testng, playwright-java

## **Overview**

Hi In ItestContexts.setAttribute() the method Page Object does not get overridden by the new pages created , I want to **dynamically update the the page value in ItestContext** on run time

## **Question**

I'm using Playwright with Java to develop a wrapper framework and I have created a custom listener class implementing **ITestListener** to take screenshot on failure using playwright methods, I only use one Page object in my test class which I overrides with new pages as wanted , but the ItestContext page reference does not get overridden by the latest page value I have set in my test method , **how can I achieve ItestContext.setAttribute to update the latest page value on run time**, as per my Test Method line 3

```
@BeforeClass
    public void init(ITestContext iTestContext) {
        iTestContext.setAttribute("Page_Reference", page); //page comes from my inherited BaseClass
    }


@Test(description = "Testing Screenshot by Overriding Practice")
    public void navDishLandPage() {
        page.goTo("https://github.com/"); //page reference comes from my base class - 1
        Page originalPage = page; //stores page reference to later access - 2
        page = getPage("User"); //Overrides the previous page reference by new Page ; getPage("Key") is a wrapper method -3
        page.goTo("https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2905");
        page = originalPage; //switching back to the stored page reference
        System.out.println(page.getTitle());
        Assert.assertEquals(page.getTitle(), "TTT");
    }
```

**Inside My onTestFailureMethod**

```
        Page page = (Page) iTestResult.getTestContext().getAttribute("Page_Reference");
        byte[] bufferImage=page.screenShot();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

- You use `ITestResult.setAttribute()` (this is one object per `@Test` method) instead of using `ITestContext.setAttribute()` (which is one object for the entire `<test>` tag). One or more `@Test` methods come under a `<test>` tag.
- Since you `getPage("User")` is your own custom method, I would suggest that you add the below lines within that method

```java
public Page getPage(String text) {
    Page page; //Your logic goes here to find the page to be returned.
    
    //Get the currently running "@Test" method's result
    ITestResult itr = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();

    // override the attribute with a reference to the latest page object being returned
    itr.setAttribute("Page_Reference", page);
    return page;
}
```

Comment: @KasunHerath - Please accept the answer if it helped so that the question also gets closed.